# Unable to make two functions work toghether

Tags: javascript, html

The scope of the code is to create a fun quiz with two choices. User can select either ‘a’ or ‘b’. When click ‘See results’ I expect to see response based on counted flagged choices.
I created two functions, `HType()` and `CheckQuiz()` which works as expected separately, but together the `CheckQuiz()` does not work.

After deep testing I concluded that the `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"` element and the for loop block in `HType()` are causing failure on `CheckQuiz()` functionality.
I have searched the net for possible solutions to make these two functions work together, (eg. `element.addEventListener('event',…`) but no success.

```js
/* Change the color of the check box and count answer */
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function HType() {
  let a = document.querySelectorAll(".mountain");
  let b = document.querySelectorAll(".beach");
  let questions = 6;
  var a_count = 0;
  var b_count = 0;
  var results;

  for (let i = 0; i < questions; i++) {
    a[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      a[i].style.backgroundColor = "orange";
      b[i].style.backgroundColor = "gray";
      a_count++;
    });
    b[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      a[i].style.backgroundColor = "gray";
      b[i].style.backgroundColor = "orange";
      b_count++;
    });
  }

  if (a_count == 0 && b_count == 0) {
    results = "n";
  } else if (a_count > b_count) {
    results = "a";
  } else {
    results = "b";
  }
  return results;
});


let x = HType();

/* Based on the returned value form above function return the responce */
function CheckQuiz() {
  if (x == "a") {
    document.addEventListener("click", HType,
      document.getElementById("HolType").innerHTML = "You are a mountain type");
  } else if (x == "b") {
    document.addEventListener("click", HType,
      document.getElementById("HolType").innerHTML = "You are a beach type");
  } else {
    document.addEventListener("click", HType,
      document.getElementById("HolType").innerHTML = "You have not selected your choice");
  }
}
```

```html
<p> Fun quiz<br> What type of holiday does suit you most?
  <br>

  <ol>
    <form onclick="HType()">
      <li>Question one: bla </li>
      <button type="button" class="mountain">a</button> You prefer this<br>
      <button type="button" class="beach">b</button> You prefer that

      <li>Question two: bla</li>
      <button type="button" class="mountain">a</button> You prefer this<br>
      <button type="button" class="beach">b</button> You prefer that

      <li>question three: bla</li>
      <button type="button" class="mountain">a</button> You prefer this<br>
      <button type="button" class="beach">b</button> You prefer that<br><br>

    </form>
  </ol>
  <form>
    <button type="button" onclick="CheckQuiz()">See Results!</button>
    <h3 id="HolType" style="text-align: center;"></h3>
  </form>
</p>
```

Comment: On those lines `document.addEventListener("click",HType,` it should end w/ a `)` instead of `,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made your code unnecessarily complex. First of all, it's not clear why did you use forms, after all, you don't submit anything. Also, if you want to add another option as "c", your code will become unmaintainable easily. That's why I've made some changes.

```js
let answers = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 0
};

let outputs = {
  a: "You are a mountain type",
  b: "You are a beach type",
  c: "You are a cave type",
  x: "You love multiple places",
  z: "You have not selected your choice"
}

const makeSelection = (answer) => {
  answer.closest(".answers")
    .querySelectorAll(".answer")
    .forEach(x => {
      if (x.classList.contains('selected')) {
        answers[x.dataset.value]--
        x.classList.remove('selected')
      }
    })
  answer.classList.add('selected');
  answers[answer.dataset.value]++
}


document.querySelectorAll(".answer")
   .forEach(answer => answer.addEventListener('click',
      () => makeSelection(answer)
   )
);

const checkQuiz = () => {
  let sorted = Object.entries(answers).sort(([,a],[,b]) => b - a)
  let result = sorted[0][1] > sorted[1][1] ? sorted[0][0] : sorted[0][1] > 0 ? "x" : "z";
  document.querySelector("#HolType").innerText = outputs[result];
}
```

```css
.selected {
  background: orange
}
```

```html
<p> Fun quiz<br> What type of holiday does suit you most?
  <br>

  <ol>
    <form>
      <li>Question one: bla </li>
      <div class="answers">
        <button type="button" class="answer mountain" data-value="a">a</button> You prefer this<br>
        <button type="button" class="answer beach" data-value="b">b</button> You prefer that<br>
        <button type="button" class="answer beach" data-value="c">c</button> Or this, maybe
      </div>
      <li>Question two: bla</li>
      <div class="answers">
        <button type="button" class="answer mountain" data-value="a">a</button> You prefer this<br>
        <button type="button" class="answer beach" data-value="b">b</button> You prefer that<br>
        <button type="button" class="answer beach" data-value="c">c</button> Or this, maybe
      </div>
      <li>question three: bla</li>
      <div class="answers">
        <button type="button" class="answer mountain" data-value="a">a</button> You prefer this<br>
        <button type="button" class="answer beach" data-value="b">b</button> You prefer that<br>
        <button type="button" class="answer beach" data-value="c">c</button> Or this, maybe
      </div>
      <li>question four: bla</li>
      <div class="answers">
        <button type="button" class="answer mountain" data-value="a">a</button> You prefer this<br>
        <button type="button" class="answer beach" data-value="b">b</button> You prefer that<br>
        <button type="button" class="answer beach" data-value="c">c</button> Or this, maybe
      </div>
    </form>
  </ol>
  <form>
    <button type="button" onclick="checkQuiz()">See Results!</button>
    <h3 id="HolType" style="text-align: center;"></h3>
  </form>
</p>
```

Comment: This answer, by running the snippet will give me exactly  what i am looking for... but unfortunately in my web pages is not working. Whe I flag the answers they do not change to orange and ialways get the 'You have not selected your choice' .. almost if the code is not registering the response.. What am I missing ?

Comment: Did you add CSS? I also added data-value attribute and extra class to the buttons, did you make the same changes?

Comment: Yes, I have a css separate style file where i added the stile suggested and also copied exactly what you posted to ensure that the extra classes and changes are included. 
I suspect that  some css properties are not allowing styles override...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how it happened.

Answer (score 0):

If you did want to use a form, I'd replace the buttons by radio-buttons, which will allow you to retrieve the value like this: `form.elements.key.value` (as well as reducing the need for highlighting code).

```js
var form = document.getElementById("quiz");

const submit = () => {
  var data = new FormData(form);

  switch (form.elements.first.value) {
    case "a":
      document.getElementById("HolType").innerHTML = "You are a mountain type";
      break;
    case "b":
      document.getElementById("HolType").innerHTML = "You are a beach type";
      break;
    default:
      document.getElementById("HolType").innerHTML = "You have not selected your choice";
      break;
  }
};
```

```html
<form id="quiz">
  Fun quiz<br> What type of holiday does suit you most?
  <br>

  <ol>
    <li>
      Question one: bla<br>
      <label>
          <input type="radio" name="first" value="a" class="mountain">A: You prefer this
        </label>
      <br>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="first" value="b" class="beach">B: You prefer that
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      Question two: bla<br>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="second" class="mountain">A: You prefer this
        </label>
      <br>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="second" class="beach">B: You prefer that
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      Question three: bla<br>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="third" class="mountain">A: You prefer this
        </label>
      <br>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="third" class="beach">B: You prefer that
        </label>
    </li>
  </ol>

</form>
<button onclick="submit()">See Results!</button>
<h3 id="HolType" style="text-align: center;"></h3>
```